# GridView commands on huge dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which displays in excess of 30000 rows, and users need to be able to edit a 'flag' (checkbox) and a 'reason' (textbox) for each row. I have thought of 2 ways to do this:

1: Postback everytime the checkbox is ticked, and save the reason and the flag on the individual row - fast if only editting one row, but becomes tedious when flags needed to be changed for multiple rows as the page needs to postback everytime, which thus rebinds the huge grid.

2: Disable auto postbacks from the checkbox, and only update the table when a global 'Update' button is pressed. This allows for fast checking/unchecking but it'd have to loop through each row to check the status - I have no idea how long this'd take and frankly I don't want to know!

Is there any other methods I could use? Perhaps using AJAX, but is it easy to use for GridViewRow's?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the above, it seems like you're not using paging.  Any reason?  If you use a data source such as LINQ, along with paging, a rebind will only be pulling and binding an amount of data equivalent to your page size.

Comment: Sorry, I am using paging - but the auto generated paging on the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're displaying the CheckBox/TextBox controls when you first load the page. If this is the case, you should absolutely **NOT** AutoPostBack. Treat this like a normal form, switch to an ASP Repeater control, pull the submitted values out of the form on a separate page, and submit them to the database then. Nothing in your question leads me to believe that you need to break the normal form submission model to accommodate the way users interact with this page.

You haven't mentioned use of the Edit/Update/Cancel buttons, which leads me to believe that you aren't using the built-in GridView commands. Honestly, it sounds to me like you're trying to make this page fit the model of a pre-existing ASP control when it really doesn't. If I were you (and had the time), I would rewrite this page using an ASP Repeater control and use jQuery to submit the page via an AJAX call to an ASP.NET WebMethod. There's a lot of jargon in that previous sentence, but once you've pulled it off the first time, it'll simplify the way you write your pages.

**Edit:** Your comment says that 30,000 was a business decision, so I removed the part of my answer indicating that you had a choice in that matter. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to do this.  If I were doing something like this that's probably the method I would you.  It will give your users a nice user experience and you won't have to worry about doing a lot of processing at the end.

On another note, if you have 30,000 records is this application going to be useful for your users?  I doubt anyone is going to look through 30,000 records and get anything useful from it...

Comment: It is rather silly displaying 30000 rows, but it's for a business system where currently, they have 30000 rows displayed. It'll go way, way down to below 100 in the future and stay that way...but I've been told they still need to edit these 30000 rows in a GridView sadly